# no module named 'dotenv' python 3.8

Tags: python, import, module

EDIT: Solved, if anyone comes across this `python3.8 -m pip install python-dotenv` worked for me.

I've tried reinstalling both dotenv and python-dotenv but I'm still getting the same error. I do have the .env file in the same directory as this script.

```
#bot.py
import os
import discord

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


token=os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


client.run(token)
```

Comment: How did you install `dotenv`?

Comment: are you sure you're not using a venv ?

Comment: can you paste what the folder tree looks like? thanks :)

Comment: I installed dotenv like this in my terminal: 
`pip install python-dotenv`

Comment: try doing `python3.8 -m pip install python-dotenv`

Comment: python3 -m pip install python-dotenv  worked for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

in your installation manager if it's Ubuntu or Debian try:
`apt install python3-dotenv`

you can also try `sudo pip3 install dotenv` to install via pip.

Whatever you do remember to include explicitly the missing **3** part.

*Debian/Ubuntu have separate packages and as of the present time `python` means `python2` and `python3` means `python3` in their apt repositories. However, when it comes to your locally installed `python` binary on your system which python binary it defaults to using may vary depending on what /usr/bin/python is symlinked to on your system. Some systems it's symlinked to something like `python2.7` and other's it may be something like `python3.5`. Similar issues exist with locally installed `pip`. Hence, why using the '3' is important when installing or searching for python packages*

Comment: Tried `pip3 install python-dotenv` and `python3-dotenv` but I'm still getting the same error. What do you mean by in my installation manager (I'm on ubuntu)?

Comment: Use the first option an install the correct package  --->`apt install python3-dotenv`

Answer (score 102):

I'm new to Python and just got exact same error. Just changed install command to what I used from a MongoDB tutorial to install PyMongo. It worked like a charm :)

```bash
python -m pip install python-dotenv
```

Answer (score 10):

This will solve just installing via terminal:

`pip3 install python-dotenv`for python 3.0 versions or `pip install python-dotenv` for python different than 3.0

Comment: I get this error: **Installing backend dependencies ...
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error.  pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.**

Answer (score 6):

### If you're using `poetry` (https://python-poetry.org), then...

Be sure you're doing:

```sh
$ poetry run SOME_COMMAND
# such as `poetry run pytest`
```

Instead of just:

```sh
$ SOME_COMMAND
# such as `pytest`
```

#### My problem (in detail) was...

```sh
# Starting with a _contrasting_ example that _unexpectedly worked_..

# A long time ago I did..

$ pip install pytest

# And now, I was doing everything below..

$ poetry add requests

# ..Then I wrote code that has `import requests` in it
# ..Then I wrote some unit test code (to use with pytest) to test the use of `requests`

# ..And NOT knowing I'm supposed to do `poetry run pytest`, I was just doing

$ pytest

# ..And it (oddly) worked, perhaps because maybe `requests` had been installed globally somewhere for me.

# ..But then I did

$ poetry add python-dotenv 

# ..Then I wrote code that had `from dotenv import load_dotenv` in it
# ..Then I wrote some unit test code (to use with pytest) to test the use of `python-dotenv`

# And I got the error I should have gotten..

$ pytest

# ..a bunch of error output, including..
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

#### Thus, the fix was:

```sh
# Get rid of the global pytest. Don't want to use that.
# (I think this step is optional, b/c I think `poetry run pytest` below will use the pytest installed via poetry in your virtual env (i.e. I _think_ it will (on it's own) NOT use the globally installed pytest.))
$ pip uninstall pytest

$ poetry add python-dotenv
$ poetry add --dev pytest

$ poetry run pytest
```

Credit for the fix goes to:

https://github.com/joeyespo/pytest-watch/issues/112

Comment: you could also use poetry shell and all following commands will be in the poetry context,
running `poetry shell`, then `SOME_COMMAND`

Comment: Any idea why I keep getting this error?  **Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file**

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue because I was running the installation command locally (in my virtual env).

When running it globally (outside of virtual env) it finally resolved the issue ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just run

```bash
pip install -U python-dotenv
```

Answer (score 3):

OK so after trying dozens of solutions here's what worked for me on MacOS (python3.10 - dotenv1.0.0) :

`pip uninstall python-dotenv`

then

`python -m pip install python-dotenv`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was aliasing `python` to `python3`, in my zsh console.

Running a `.py` file with `python3 -i filename.py` made it work.

Comment: Yes I was facing this issue in VS Code, and I had to run the actual `.py` file.  It works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (Python 3.8.5, dotenv 0.15.0) and was getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv' in both the console and JupyterLab. All other packages seemed to install via pip with no problems.

I just ran:

pip3 uninstall python-dotenv

pip3 install -U python-dotenv

Answer (score 1):

Installing the package globally and not in your virtual environment!
pip install python-dotenv

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.8.8 version Anaconda Jupyter

Command to install dotenv library:

pip install python-dotenv

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal you have to activate your virtual environment and run

```
pip3 install python-dotenv
```

for python 3.0 versions . OR,

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

for python bigger than 3.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case got this error while running `pytest`.
Issue got resolved by calling `python3 -m pytest` <- inside poetry

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and tried everything here, but once I closed out of my terminal windows and reopened them, the library was finally recognized.

Answer (score 0):

This is only tangentially related,but maybe it helps some:
`python-dotenv` is often the first dependency being loaded by your Python application, so if `python-dotenv` is not found, it might mean that no dependencies are installed at all.

In my case, I had to make sure my Azure Web Application was configured correctly, by setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` and `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` both to true.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying all above mentioned options but finally this command worked for me on windows.

```
py -m pip install python-dotenv
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to install it as `py-dotenv` which installs some other package. Which perhaps is the very first version of python-dotenv as it is labeled as `0.1`.

Answer (score -1):

It is caused because there is really no library named as `dotenv` .
In python this library is named as `python-dotenv` for `python3.11.0`.

so just run the following command below

windows

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

ubuntu

```
apt install python3-dotenv
```

Comment: The top-rated and accepted answers from 3.5 years ago already cover this. Please don't repeat answers.