# unable to install python-dotenv in python in script running on Azure Machine Learning experiment

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-pipelines

I created a new experiment in Azure Machine Learning to run an endpoint of a Python script. The Python script itself runs fine but then when I run the driver of the Python script, I get an error when I try to run `python-dotenv`.

All of these statements throw an `SyntaxError: invalid syntax error`:

```
get_ipython().system('pip install python-dotenv')
pip install --upgrade python-dotenv
pip install python-dotenv
pip install -U python-dotenv
!pip install python-dotenv
```

If I don't try to install `python-dotenv`, I get this error:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv  # pip install python-dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

Comment: Did you try running `pip` from the console? (If not found, you can use `where pip`, the full path or add it to the system environment path and restart the console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly using `pip install <name>` you can use the `python -m pip install <name>`

I had tried with `pip install` Some times it may given the syntax error while accessing outside of the installed directory. Instead you can use `python -m pip install <name>`.

Make sure Your `Pip version` should be **latest** or try to update by using `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Use the below snippet to install the Python-dotenv

```
python -m pip install --upgrade python-dotenv
python -m pip install python-dotenv
python -m pip install -U python-dotenv
python -m !pip install python-dotenv
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572174/no-module-named-dotenv-python-3-8/59572201)

Note: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you