# pip install for Azure web app with custom deploy script

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm pushing a Flask web app to azure from a local git repo.  The app has a `.deployment` file that points to `scripts/deploy.sh` that runs an `npm run build` action and copies the generated build to the app's static folder.

The azure docs suggest that placing `requirements.txt` at the top of the repo will automatically run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  I can't see any evidence that this command is running and I wonder if the custom deployment script overrides it.  If I explicitly call this command in the file, I see:

`scripts/deploy.sh: line 20: pip: command not found`

This seems to be because the container built at deployment has its own virtual environment. How do I convince the deployment process to run pip install in the virtual environment?

Application log after build and launch:

```
2024-03-27T04:38:07.838468802Z: [INFO]  Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/tmp/8dc4df81676606a/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages'
2024-03-27T04:38:07.914410500Z: [ERROR]  Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-03-27T04:38:07.915612203Z: [ERROR]    File "/tmp/8dc4df81676606a/backend/app.py", line 6, in <module>
2024-03-27T04:38:07.916790406Z: [ERROR]      from dotenv import load_dotenv
2024-03-27T04:38:07.917807108Z: [ERROR]  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---Starting Live Log Stream ---
```

EDIT: specifying `python3-dotenv` instead of `python-dotenv` did not resolve the issue. Neither did setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no module named 'dotenv' python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572174/no-module-named-dotenv-python-3-8)

Comment: Maybe? I have python-dotenv in my requirements file but maybe I need to explicitly ask for python3-dotenv. Thing is, there is nothing in the deployment logs to suggest that pip ran at all.

Comment: Followup: renaming to python3-dotenv did not solve the issue.  I'm almost certain pip install never runs. Also, I manually set SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=1 in the app settings

Comment: @RobertSim, Please provide your project repository link(if possible) if available in GitHub.

Comment: @PravallikaKV here is the repo: git@github.com:simra/frcScout.git

Comment: I have determined that if I use a .deployment file then the Oryx build is skipped completely and I need to include all deployment steps in the deployment script. I changed my build process to build locally on a deployment branch and push the branch, removing the need for a remote deployment file. I'll leave the question unanswered in case someone can demonstrate how to trigger Oryx.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the virtual environment by adding below commands in the deployment script `deploy.sh`:

```bash
source <path_to_virtualenv/bin/activate> (i.e.,source antenv/bin/activate)

pip install -r <path_of_requirements.txt>
```

I have created a flask application and used below code:

```py
from  dotenv  import  load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

- Created virtual environment(**env**) to install the packages using the commands:

```py
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

**Folder Structure:**

```
│   .gitignore
│   app.py
│   CHANGELOG.md
│   CONTRIBUTING.md
│   LICENSE.md
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
├───.github
├───env
├───static
└───templates
```

- Deployed the application to Azure App Service using Local GIT.

```
(env) C:\Users\uname\flaskapp>git push azure main:master
Enumerating objects: 125, done.
Counting objects: 100% (125/125), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (63/63), done.
Writing objects: 100% (125/125), 785.30 KiB | 39.26 MiB/s, done.
Total 125 (delta 56), reused 125 (delta 56), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (56/56), done.
remote: Deploy Async
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '223b3cf48e'.
remote: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
remote: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
remote: Repository path is /home/site/repository
remote: Running oryx build...
remote: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
remote: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
remote:
remote: Oryx Version: 0.2.20230508.1, Commit: 7fe2bf39b357dd68572b438a85ca50b5ecfb4592, ReleaseTagName: 20230508.1
remote:
remote: Build Operation ID: 006694baf2ca5e2b
remote: Repository Commit : 223b3cf48eb78f055f670202ead044e98ab0360a
remote: OS Type           : bullseye
remote: Image Type        : githubactions
remote:
remote: Detecting platforms...
remote: Detected following platforms:
remote:   python: 3.11.8
remote: Version '3.11.8' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
remote:
remote: Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8dc4efcb326576d'.
remote:
remote: Copying files to the intermediate directory...
remote: Done in 0 sec(s).
remote:
remote: Source directory     : /tmp/8dc4efcb326576d
remote: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
remote: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.11.8' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8'...
remote: Detected image debian flavor: bullseye.
remote: Downloaded in 2 sec(s).
remote: Verifying checksum...
remote: Extracting contents...
remote: performing sha512 checksum for: python...
remote: Done in 6 sec(s).
remote:
remote: image detector file exists, platform is python..
remote: OS detector file exists, OS is bullseye..
remote: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8/bin/python3.11
remote: Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
remote: Removing existing manifest file
remote: Python Virtual Environment: antenv
remote: Creating virtual environment...
remote: Activating virtual environment...
remote: Running pip install...
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting Flask==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading Flask-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting gunicorn (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading gunicorn-21.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting Werkzeug==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.4 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting Jinja2>=3.0 (from Flask==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading Jinja2-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0 (from Flask==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting click>=8.0 (from Flask==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.1.1 (from Werkzeug==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Collecting packaging (from gunicorn->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote: [07:57:35+0000]   Downloading packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading Flask-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000]    ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü 101.5/101.5 kB 28.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000]    ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü 232.7/232.7 kB 75.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading gunicorn-21.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000]    ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü∩┐╜∩┐╜ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü 80.2/80.2 kB 35.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000]    ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü 97.9/97.9 kB 41.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading Jinja2-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000]    ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü 133.2/133.2 kB 51.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (28 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Downloading packaging-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
remote: [07:57:35+0000]    ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü 53.5/53.5 kB 17.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
remote: [07:57:35+0000] Installing collected packages: packaging, MarkupSafe, itsdangerous, click, Werkzeug, Jinja2, gunicorn, Flask
remote: [07:57:36+0000] Successfully installed Flask-2.2.2 Jinja2-3.1.3 MarkupSafe-2.1.5 Werkzeug-2.2.2 click-8.1.7 gunicorn-21.2.0 itsdangerous-2.1.2 packaging-24.0
remote: Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
remote: Preparing output...
remote:
remote: Copying files to destination directory '/tmp/_preCompressedDestinationDir'...
remote: Done in 0 sec(s).
remote: Compressing content of directory '/tmp/_preCompressedDestinationDir'...
remote: Copied the compressed output to '/home/site/wwwroot'
remote:
remote: Removing existing manifest file
remote: Creating a manifest file...
remote: Manifest file created.
remote: Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.
remote:
remote: Done in 13 sec(s).
remote: Running post deployment command(s)...
remote:
remote: Generating summary of Oryx build
remote: Parsing the build logs
remote: Found 0 issue(s)
remote:
remote: Build Summary :
remote: ===============
remote: Errors (0)
remote: Warnings (0)
remote:
remote: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
remote: Deployment successful. deployer =  deploymentPath =
remote: Deployment Logs : 'https://kpflaskapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/jsonviewer?view_url=/api/deployments/223b3cf48eb78f055f670202ead044e98ab0360a/log'
To https://kpflaskapp.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/kpflaskapp.git
 * [new branch]      main -> master
```

**App Service Logs:**

```
2024-03-28T09:30:53.366091831Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-03-28T09:30:53.366095719Z Python 3.11.7
2024-03-28T09:30:53.366099887Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-03-28T09:30:53.857082966Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-03-28T09:30:53.876787582Z App Command Line not configured, will attempt auto-detect
2024-03-28T09:30:53.876977196Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite
2024-03-28T09:30:53.936844682Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2024-03-28T09:30:53.939444394Z Build Operation ID: 006694baf2ca5e2b
2024-03-28T09:30:53.940956897Z Output is compressed. Extracting it...
2024-03-28T09:30:53.940981173Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20240127.1, Commit: 4b7f2dffcc69c214f9806d67a85ec8926e2393e1, ReleaseTagName: 20240127.1
2024-03-28T09:30:53.942382458Z Extracting '/home/site/wwwroot/output.tar.gz' to directory '/tmp/8dc4efcb326576d'...
2024-03-28T09:30:54.520441476Z App path is set to '/tmp/8dc4efcb326576d'
2024-03-28T09:30:54.553473156Z Detected an app based on Flask
2024-03-28T09:30:54.553544960Z Generating `gunicorn` command for 'app:app'
2024-03-28T09:30:54.555519014Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-03-28T09:30:54.584079610Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /tmp/8dc4efcb326576d/antenv.
2024-03-28T09:30:54.584102352Z Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/tmp/8dc4efcb326576d/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages'
2024-03-28T09:30:54.842338343Z [2024-03-28 09:30:54 +0000] [73] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2024-03-28T09:30:54.854736676Z [2024-03-28 09:30:54 +0000] [73] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (73)
2024-03-28T09:30:54.854796869Z [2024-03-28 09:30:54 +0000] [73] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2024-03-28T09:30:54.858336021Z [2024-03-28 09:30:54 +0000] [76] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 76
2024-03-28T09:30:55.499981679Z 172.16.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024:09:30:55 +0000] "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "HealthCheck/1.0"
2024-03-28T09:30:56.121392969Z Request for index page received
2024-03-28T09:30:56.121424398Z 172.16.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024:09:30:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1469 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0"
2024-03-28T09:30:56.543593372Z 172.16.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024:09:30:56 +0000] "GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://kpflaskapp.azurewebsites.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0"
2024-03-28T09:30:56.547191577Z 172.16.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024:09:30:56 +0000] "GET /static/images/azure-icon.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://kpflaskapp.azurewebsites.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0"
2024-03-28T09:30:57.350264488Z Request for index page received
2024-03-28T09:30:57.350299212Z 172.16.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024:09:30:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1469 "-" "AlwaysOn"
2024-03-28T09:30:57.896618043Z 172.16.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024:09:30:57 +0000] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://kpflaskapp.azurewebsites.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0"
2024-03-28T09:31:07.346168021Z Request for index page received2024-03-28T09:31:07.346213867Z 172.16.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2024:09:31:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1469 "-" "AlwaysOn"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will try this over the weekend. When/where do you invoke `py -m venv env`? Is that placed into the deployment script?  I don't see evidence of the oryx invocation in my deployment logs. 

remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '44c3e61ecc'.
remote: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
remote: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
remote: Running custom deployment command...
remote: Not setting execute permissions for bash scripts/deploy.sh
remote: Running deployment command...